# How to populate text areas with the contents of dropdown url choices?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

Okay, well, I guess it all boils down to this: how can I improve this code...

```
    <br><br>
    <select id="newText">
        <option value="url1">tool_ver1</option>
        <option value="url2">tool_ver2</option>
        <option value="url2" selected >tool_ver3</option>
    </select>
    <br><br>
    <button type="submit">Retrieve New Release App Options</button>
    <br><br>
```

To fill the following textarea...

```
    <div class="textInput spacer">
        <h2>New Release App Options</h2>
        <textarea id="newText"></textarea>
    </div>
```

In the end, textarea needs to be filled with the contents of whatever url is selected for newText. I cannot get the submit button to do what I hope/expect.

Comment: This question is too broad, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and update your question.

Answer (score 1):

with jQuery, select the element and use the `val` method. In pure js, query for the element and use the `value` member.

```js
//jQuery
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("textarea#mytextarea").val("My value");
});

//OR pure js
document.getElementById('mytextarea').value = 'My value';
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id='mytextarea'></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple answer using pure js without jquery.
You can modify this to work on "submit" if you want but I have it working on "change".

```js
const select = document.getElementById('select')
const newText = document.getElementById('newText')

select.addEventListener("change", e => {
  console.log(e.target.value)
  newText.value = e.target.value
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <select id="select">
    <option value="url1">tool_ver1</option>
    <option value="url2">tool_ver2</option>
    <option value="url3" selected >tool_ver3</option>
  </select>
  <button type="submit">Retrieve New Release App Options</button>
<div class="textInput spacer">
  <h2>New Release App Options</h2>
  <textarea id="newText"></textarea>
</div>
  
  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're getting hung up because your <select> menu and your <textarea> have the same ID.  Here is a working JSFiddle that updates the contents of <textarea> every time you change the value in the <select> menu.  You could just as easily rejigger it to update based on the click of the button, if you prefer.

https://jsfiddle.net/bytebodger/zct0po47/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    const currentValue = $('#newText').val();
    $('#selectedOption').empty().append(currentValue);
    $('#newText').on('change', function(event) {
        const currentValue = $('#newText').val();
        $('#selectedOption').empty().append(currentValue);
    });
});
```

Comment: That was a big help, thanks! One last question: how can I get the url1, url2, etc., options (which are intranet web pages of text-only information) read directly into the newText and baseText text areas? That is all I have left to do...

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question.  If you're saying that you want to then grab the *contents* of the chosen URL and display it in the `<textarea>`, that will take a little more work.  You would have to make a separate HTTP request to grab that content.  You won't be able to do that with Javascript/jQuery/AJAX unless you can make CORS requests to those domains.  If you can't do the CORS requests with JS, then you'll need to use a server-side language to grab the contents and then return them to the browser.  This would often be done with cURL.

Answer (score 0):

For closure, this ended up working for me. Thanks to all who helped out--much appreciated!

```
<body>
    <h1 class="top"> Check application option default settings between two releases</h1>
    <div class="top"><br>
    <button type="submit">Select Release #1</button>
    <select id="selectedBaseRelease">
        <option value="https://wwwin/~ckennedy/releases/K-2015.06.AppOp.Defaults.txt" selected >ICC2_K-2015.06</option>
        <option value="https://wwwin/~ckennedy/releases/L-2016.03.AppOp.Defaults.txt">ICC2_L-2016.03</option>
        <option value="https://wwwin/~ckennedy/releases/M-2016.12.AppOp.Defaults.txt">ICC2_M-2016.12</option>
        <option value="https://wwwin/~ckennedy/releases/N-2017.09.AppOp.Defaults.txt">ICC2_N-2017.09</option>
        <option value="https://wwwin/~ckennedy/releases/O-2018.06.AppOp.Defaults.txt">ICC2_O-2018.06</option>
    </select>
    <br><br>
    <button type="submit">Select Release #2</button>
    <select id="selectedNewRelease">
        <option value="https://wwwin/~ckennedy/releases/K-2015.06.AppOp.Defaults.txt">ICC2_K-2015.06</option>
        <option value="https://wwwin/~ckennedy/releases/L-2016.03.AppOp.Defaults.txt" selected >ICC2_L-2016.03</option>
        <option value="https://wwwin/~ckennedy/releases/M-2016.12.AppOp.Defaults.txt">ICC2_M-2016.12</option>
        <option value="https://wwwin/~ckennedy/releases/N-2017.09.AppOp.Defaults.txt">ICC2_N-2017.09</option>
        <option value="https://wwwin/~ckennedy/releases/O-2018.06.AppOp.Defaults.txt">ICC2_O-2018.06</option>
    </select>
    <br><br>
    </div>
    <div class="top">
        <strong>Context size (optional):</strong> <input type="text" id="contextSize" value="" />
    </div>
    <div class="textInput spacer">
        <h2>Release #1 App Option Defaults</h2>
        <textarea class="textbox" id="baseText"></textarea>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                const currentBaseValue = $('#selectedBaseRelease').val();
                $('#baseText').empty().append(currentBaseValue);
                $('#selectedBaseRelease').on('change', function(event) {
                    const currentBaseValue = $('#selectedBaseRelease').val();
                    $('#baseText').empty().load(currentBaseValue)
                });
            });
        </script>
    </div>
    <div class="textInput spacer">
        <h2>Release #2 App Option Defaults</h2>
        <textarea class="textbox" id="newText"></textarea>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                const currentNewValue = $('#selectedNewRelease').val();
                $('#newText').empty().append(currentNewValue);
                $('#selectedNewRelease').on('change', function(event) {
                    const currentNewValue = $('#selectedNewRelease').val();
                    $('#newText').empty().load(currentNewValue)
                });
            });
        </script>
    </div>
    <div class="viewType">
        <input type="radio" name="_viewtype" id="sidebyside" onclick="diffUsingJS(0);" /> <label for="sidebyside">Side by Side Diff</label>
        &nbsp; &nbsp;
        <input type="radio" name="_viewtype" id="inline" onclick="diffUsingJS(1);" /> <label for="inline">Inline Diff</label>
    </div>
    <div id="diffoutput"> </div>
</body>
```